# Angular - Logged in user name not being displayed

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I am developing an application using Laravel-5.8 as the backend and Angular-7 as the frontend.

This is the flow of the Application:

1. authentication.service
2. login.component
3. navtop.component

Laravel

```
    public function login() {
        $authenticated = false;
        // 'remember_me' => 'boolean'
        $remember = request('remember') ? true : false;
        if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')], $remember)) {
            $authenticated = true;
        } 
        if ($authenticated == true) {
            $user = Auth::guard('web')->user();
            $date = date('Y-m-d');

            $success['userId'] = $user->id;
            $success['avatar'] = url('/storage/user') . '/' . $user->avatar;
            // $success['points'] = $user->userPoints->sum('points');
            $success['email'] = $user->email;
            $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
            return $this->returnResponse(true, $success);
        } else {
            $success = array();
            return $this->returnResponse(false, $success, 1, 'Invalid User Credential');
        }
    }
```

Angular

authentication.service-ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  isLoginSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.hasToken());

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

   private hasToken(): boolean {

    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
      const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
        return true;
      }  else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}

    /*
      Date: 01-09-2019
      Created By: Michael Idowu
      Purpose: update login status
      =============================
    */
   setLoginSubject(status: boolean) {
    this.isLoginSubject.next(status);
  }

  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.isLoginSubject.asObservable();
  }


   register(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/register', user);
  }

  login(user: any) {
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiUrl + '/login', user)
        .pipe(map(response => {
          if (response.data && response.data.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response.data));
            this.isLoginSubject.next(true);
          }
          return response;
      }));
  }

  getUserDetails() {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/userDetails', {});
  }

}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
// import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
// import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
// import { AuthService } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { FacebookLoginProvider } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../core/auth/services/authentication.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';

declare var $;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild ('validateform') validateform: NgForm;
  config: any;
  loginModel: any = {};
  name: string;
  @Input() userInfo: any;
  @Input() userLoginStatus: boolean;

  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    document.body.className = 'hold-transition login-page';
    $(() => {
      $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
        increaseArea: '20%' /* optional */
      });
    });

    const loggedInSubscriber = this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();
    loggedInSubscriber.subscribe(response => {
        this.userLoginStatus = response;
    });

    // check for the user data if logged in
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
      const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      this.userInfo = currentUser;
    }
    this.config = environment;
    this.name = 'Test name';
  }

 onLogin(loginform: any) {
  if (!loginform.valid) { // return false if form not valid
    return false;
  }
  this.spinnerService.show();
  this.loginModel.remember = 1;
  this.authenticationService.login(this.loginModel)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          if (!response['success']) {

            this.toastr.error(response['message']);
            return false;
          }
          this.userInfo = response['data'];
          this.toastr.success('Login Successful.');
          loginform.reset();
          loginform.resetForm();
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
          // added to refresh the component
          // this.router.navigateByUrl('/home', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() =>
          //   this.router.navigate(['home']));
        },
        error => {
          this.spinnerService.hide();
            this.toastr.error(error);
        }
      );
}
}
```

navtop.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../core/auth/services/authentication.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navtop',
  templateUrl: './navtop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navtop.component.scss']
})
export class NavtopComponent implements OnInit {

  config: any;
  name: string;

  points: number;
  registerModel: any = {};
  loginModel: any = {};
  forgotModel: any = {};
  validateModel: any = {};
  navbarOpen = false;
  @Input() userInfo: any;
  @Input() userLoginStatus: boolean;



  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const loggedInSubscriber = this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();

    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {

      const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

      this.authenticationService.setLoginSubject(true);
      const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      this.userInfo = currentUser;
      this.config = environment;
      this.name = 'Test name';
      const loggedInSubscriber = this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();
      loggedInSubscriber.subscribe(response => {
        this.userLoginStatus = response;
      });
    }

  }
}
```

navtop.component.html

```
<p>
   Welcome, {{userInfo.name}}
</p>
```

After successful login, the username suppose to be displayed on the navbar immediately after Welcome, but nothing is being displayed.

[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8YD7.png)

Comment: can you attach a stackblitz of your angular code?

Comment: @ Iftifar Taz - I dontknow how to do that

Comment: this is a async prob you should move your code inside subscribe method of login, you are trying to fetch locastorage before subscribing

Comment: How do I move it to subscribe? Am new to Angular